# Take care of gap in lawn before winter or wait until spring?

Tags: lawn-repair, winter-gardening

I had a concrete walkway removed that separated my lawn into two sections. Now I need to fill the gap with soil. It is November already and sod is not available anymore. Should I do something now or can I wait until spring and leave the soil as is over autumn and winter?

I am in the US, New York State.

Comment: Please tell us where is this lawn located.

Comment: Yep, where are you in the world please

Comment: @Alina oops, sorry... please see my edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leave it as is until sod is available in the spring. Just don't walk in that area during winter, to avoid soil compacting.

In spring, some minor work will be needed to prepare the area for sod, but new grass or weed will not appear by then, for all intents and purposes.

Answer (score 3):

I reckon put off today what you can do later to give yourself more time to think about it and consider your options. There's no rush and who knows you make wake up in the middle of the night with a brilliant off the wall creative Kiwi solution. You wouldn't be the first either.

Answer (score 3):

You can put soil in if you find a good deal, but don't bother with sod or seed, this is not the growing season for your area. (Michigan here.)